# How to get user id from the related field model in django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

views.py

```
 @login_required
def become_vendor(request):
vendordetailform = VendorAdminDetailsForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    vendordetailform = VendorAdminDetailsForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    
    if vendordetailform.is_valid():    
        vendordetailform.instance.vendoruser = request.user      
        request.user=vendordetailform.save()
        request.user.is_active=False
        request.user.save()
        user_details = CustomUser.objects.filter(id=request.user)
        vendor_details = user_details[0].vendor_details.all()
        return render(request,'vendor/preview.html', {'user_details':user_details, 'vendor_details':vendor_details})
else:
    vendordetailform = VendorAdminDetailsForm()


return render(request, 'vendor/become_vendor.html', {'vendordetailform':vendordetailform})
```

models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

username = None
email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True) 
mobile_number = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=True)    
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
vendor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
# is_approved = models.BooleanField(default=True)

id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=True)
userid= models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, null=True)

objects = UserManager()

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.email)+ '-' + self.userid

class VendorDetails(models.Model):
vendoruser = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='vendor_details')
type_of_vendor = models.CharField(max_length=200)
aadhar_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
aadhar_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='Images')
pan_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
pan_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='Images')
store_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
mail_id = models.EmailField(max_length=200)
contact_no = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
gst_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
attach_gst_cert = models.ImageField(upload_to='Images')
acct_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
attach_passbook = models.ImageField(upload_to='Images')
ifsc_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
fb_account = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, null=True)
insta_account = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, null=True) 
website = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, null=True)
door_no = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, null=True)
street_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
pincode = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)


def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id) + " - " +str(self.vendoruser)
```

I have two models 1. User model, 2. VendorDetails model (vendoruser is connected by foreignkey relationship with vendordetails)
Here I save the User extra details (VendorDetailsForm) if the requested user is applying for a vendor. I could be saved the requested user details in VendorDetails Model. But when I am getting the requested user id, I can't . instead I get vendordetails model foreignkey field. Here I want to inactive the requested user who came with this vendor details form. I am getting `Field 'id' expected a number but got <VendorDetails: yabeshofz@gmail.com-Customer1>.`

Comment: could you please share your model ?

Comment: shared model in the question.

Comment: does the answer below solve your problem ?

Comment: not yet. I got the id from the VendorDetails model for this line. `user_details = CustomUser.objects.filter(id=request.user.id)`. I need to get the CustomUser model id for the requested user.

Comment: i posted my answer try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is that you are assigning `request.user` to `vendordetailform.save()` that is not correct remove that line and pass `request.user.id` to `CustomUser`
Try something like this.

```
@login_required
def become_vendor(request):
vendordetailform = VendorAdminDetailsForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    vendordetailform = VendorAdminDetailsForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    
    if vendordetailform.is_valid():    
        vendordetailform.instance.vendoruser = request.user      
        vendordetailform.save() 
        request.user.is_active=False
        request.user.save()
        user_details = CustomUser.objects.filter(id=request.user.id) 
        vendor_details = user_details[0].vendordetails_set.all()
        return render(request,'vendor/preview.html', {'user_details':user_details, 'vendor_details':vendor_details})
else:
    vendordetailform = VendorAdminDetailsForm()


return render(request, 'vendor/become_vendor.html', {'vendordetailform':vendordetailform})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead : `user_details = CustomUser.objects.filter(id=request.user.id)`

```
if vendordetailform.is_valid():    
    # Some code ...
    user_details = CustomUser.objects.filter(id=request.user.id)
    # Some code ...
```